# Where is BigData datastore INSERT statement and Java API library?

Tags: datastore, bigdata, insert-statement

I was given a task to create a graph data in BigData datastore. Here BigData is RDF datastore.   But the problem I even couldn'd find an INSERT statement to it? Is there any sample to INSERT and store data?

And where is the Java API library to it?

Here BigData is RDF datastore. More can be found here http://www.systap.com/bigdata.htm .

Comment: I could not understand the term Big Data datastore. Do you mean to say the HDFS in hadoop, HBase or hive? Could you be a bit more specific.

Comment: http://www.bigdata.com/bigdata/docs/api/ this is the bigdata api docs I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Insert statement is not supported in SPARQL versions before 1.1
So make sure your datastore support atleast SPARQL 1.1
In some datastores like stardog even though it support  SPARQL 1.1 they removed UPDATE,INSERT ,and DELETE features due to some security reasons.

If you datastore support SPARQL 1.1  and INSERT Here is the query

```
INSERT DATA 
{
  <http://example.org/subject> <http://example.org/predicate> <http://example.org/object> 
}
```

or

```
INSERT DATA 
{ 
  GRAPH <http://example.org/myGraph> 
  { 
    <http://example.org/subject> <http://example.org/predicate> <http://example.org/object> 
  }
}
```